# Unable to verify/create output bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-athena

I'm trying to query Amazon Athena for the end result of an ETL job. Everything in AWS is working fine, but now that I need to access it from my Rails app, I'm running into issues.
I've read the questions and answers relating to this topic on both the aws forums and here. None seem to work as they all revolve around IAM permission. I have god powers in my org.

The region in the bucket and the sdk client match

My permissions are:

```json
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "*",
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

The bucket is public; for now, while I test. But no matter what I do, I continue to receive this error

`Unable to verify/create output bucket bucket-name`

Here is the block of code I am trying to use to query Athena:

```rb
client = Aws::Athena::Client.new # region/access key/secret key are set in the intializer.
client.start_query_execution({
                               query_string: "SELECT * FROM \"database\".\"table\" limit 10;",
                               result_configuration: {
                                 output_location: "s3://bucket-name/aws-athena-query-results/",
                                 encryption_configuration: {
                                   encryption_option: "SSE_S3"
                                 }
                               }
                             })
```

Thanks in advance for any help given :D

Comment: Is the Amazon S3 bucket in the same region as the region where Amazon Athena is being called? They might need to be in the same region.

Comment: I got excited there for a minute, bc when I'm on the s3 page, it says global. But the properties in the bucket list it as the same region from the command I run with the Rails SDK. I even tried to initialize a new Athena Client instance with the region and all but still get the same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in my case, it was the force MFA permissions put in place by our DevOps Lead. Temporarily removing my IAM user from that group allowed Athena access. They are now going to assist my in creating/modifying a permission to allow Athena access even with MFA enabled for my account

Comment: Glad you figured it out! You could, if necessary, call `GetSessionToken()` with an MFA code, but it's easier to avoid having to use an MFA.

Comment: ya, we're going to set up different credentials that have properly scoped permissions, etc. That way, admins can stay admins, but the parts of the app that need this functionality to only have this. But thanks for the `GetSessionToken()` idea. Might come in handy in the future :D I'm only jsut starting to dive into AWS at work :D